# Which LN volumes are covered in season 1&2 of "Konosuba" anime?

Tags: konosuba

I just finished watching season 1&2 of *Konosuba*. I want to start reading the light novel.

From which volume should I start?

Comment: very often things got changed/cut for the anime adaptation so it may be worth reading from the start anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E7%B4%A0%E6%99%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AB%E7%A5%9D%E7%A6%8F%E3%82%92!&oldid=74900389#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88):

- Volume 1 covers Season 1, Episode 1 (S1E1) - S1E6
- Volume 2 covers S1E7 - S1E10 *and S2E3*
- Volume 3 covers S2E1 - S2E5 *except S2E3*
- Volume 4 covers S2E6 - S2E10

So, you might want to start from Volume 5.

However, take a moment to read [Is the Konosuba anime a close adaptation of the light novel?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30582/is-the-konosuba-anime-a-close-adaptation-of-the-light-novel?rq=1) to decide whether you want to read from the beginning instead.

Comment: Wiz was introduced in a flashback, so i might start from the beginning. Did they skipped any other important details in the anime?

Comment: @trim24 Sorry, I don't follow the series though. You might ask that as a new question though.