# Where to start reading KonoSuba light novel after watching the anime and movie?

Tags: konosuba

I finished the *KonoSuba* anime and movie and would like to know what chapter/volume of the light novel should I start reading at.

Answer (score 1):

The *KonoSuba* anime covers [the first 4 volumes of the light novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/42909/2516), and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KonoSuba:_God%27s_Blessing_on_this_Wonderful_World!_Legend_of_Crimson), the *Legend of Crimson* movie was based on Volume 5 of the light novel, *Crimson Magic Clan, Let's & Go!!*.

So, you might want to start from Volume 6, but take note that [there are always differences between the adaptation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30582/2516).